# Regex help needed to improve performance and reduce backtracking

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a not very well structured server log of a game server to extract information. However my regex performs quite poorly, especially when dealing with larger logs.

```regex
(?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} > MAPSTART.*?\n)(?:.*?\r?\n?)*?)(?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) > \[M\] statslib: DUMP BEGIN((?:.*?\r?\n?)*)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} > \[M\] statslib: DUMP END)\n
```

See https://regex101.com/r/4AS2Ke/1 for an example of a log snippet.

I am trying to extract these properties:

`2021-01-01 05:09:10 > MAPSTART: map06: Map15`

`2021-01-01 05:09:10 > { "map": "map05", "duration": 619, "monsters_killed": 419`

Also note: either `2021-01-01 05:09:10 Stopped demo recording` or

```
2021-01-01 05:09:10 > [M] statslib: DUMP BEGIN
2021-01-01 05:09:10 > { "map": "map05", "duration": 619, "monsters_killed": 419,
2021-01-01 05:09:10 > ... (rest of the json lines)
2021-01-01 05:09:10 > ]
2021-01-01 05:09:10 > [M] statslib: DUMP END
```

can be absent from the logs, depending on the game server setup.

For the most part, the regex I crafted works, just performs very poorly. Larger logs take a very long time to process.

You can see an example of it running here and the performance:
https://regex101.com/r/4AS2Ke/1

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong in the regex, or something I should be doing differently?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/4AS2Ke/2

Comment: Thanks, that seems quite an improvement. Can you explain a little how this improves it?

Comment: If it does what you need, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match whole lines with a greedy dot pattern, `.*` while removing the unnecessary `\r?` (a `.` in a Python regex matches a CR, too), and making `\n` obligatory (`\n?` -> `\n`).

You can use

```py
(?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} > MAPSTART.*\n)(?:.*\n)*?)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) > \[M\] statslib: DUMP BEGIN((?:.*\n)*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} > \[M\] statslib: DUMP END\n
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AS2Ke/2).

For example, see `(?:.*?\r?\n?)*?`. This pattern matches zero or more times, but as few as possible, sequences of: any zero or more chars other than a line feed char as few as possible, then an optional CR and then an optional LF. All patterns are *optional* and there are a really huge lot of ways to match a part of a string with this subpattern. Turning it into `(?:.*\n)*?` makes it way faster because the greedy `.*` pattern grabs the whole line up to an LF char at once, and as `\n` is obligatory, there is no way for backtracking to fall through to the `.*` after matching a newline.